# Can't install aircrack-ng

Tags: command-line, aircrack-ng

Whenever I attempt to install `aircrack-ng` in terminal I get the following error:

```
Package aircrack-ng is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  iw

E: Package 'aircrack-ng' has no installation candidate"
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and so have no idea what to do.

Comment: i downloaded the tar ball and compiled it...

Comment: Has any of the offered answers helped? Please click the checkmark if any of them has.

Answer (score 18):

It has been removed from ubuntu repositories as message says. you can install it by doing following procedure

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.1
```

In the aircrack-ng-1.1 directory there is a file called common.mak, use your favorite editor to open the file and scroll down till you see the following line:

```
CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3
```

Delete the `-Werror` variable, so that the line now looks like the following. Save and exit.

```
CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -O3
```

Run `make` and `sudo make install` in terminal to get `aircrack-ng` up and running."

For `build-essential` go to update manager > settings > ubuntu softwares and see if top main is checked.

[image]

Comment: when i do the first instruction : 'sudo apt-get install build-essential' i get the response ( Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate )

Comment: That is an essential part of ubuntu, it should work. please check you typed it correctly. and also you mentioned in comments about libc6. whenever some application tries to give you this kind of message, copy that (e.g libc6) and paste it in synpatic package manager, then install it.

Comment: or for libc6 enter in terminal sudo apt-get install libc6

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I can only use the aircrack-ng command. I cannot use airmon-ng, airodump-ng, aireplay-ng, etc...

Answer (score 7):

[I have it in a PPA for precise](https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/aircrack-precise).  I did it for another question.  If you need directions for adding a PPA they're [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: Lol was going to mention this here. That I knew that the user aking has a PPA with it. Already installed aircrack from there. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not in the repositories anymore. I know that `aircrack-ng` was in the Ubuntu 10.10 repositories, so you might want to try using Ubuntu 10.10 instead of the current version (12.04). But you can also install it in 12.04, using another way. You'll then install `aircrack-ng` using a `.deb` file. You just double-click on this file, and it will be opened in the Ubuntu Software Center. To get the `.deb` file for a 32-bit Ubuntu install (i386), click [here](http://ubuntu2.cica.es/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.1-1_i386.deb). If you're using a 64-bit Ubuntu install (amd64), click [here](http://ubuntu2.cica.es/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.1-1_amd64.deb).

Comment: i see, ok well is there another type of thing that is the same as aircrack-ng for the new version (12.04) ?

Comment: Yes, the files I'm referring to are installable on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: And those files are the 'real' `aircrack-ng`, what you're talking about.

Comment: i clicked there and it went to software centre and i could see the aircrack-ng and the page is greyed out and i cant press anything also there is a message saying ' dependancy is not satisfiable: libc6 (>=2.7)

Comment: That's strange. On my install, it went just fine. Your best option then would be to follow @aking1012 's solution, because that's relatively easy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Debian packages are available here : http://ubuntu2.cica.es/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aircrack-ng/

You need to download the respective package architecture

```
wget http://ubuntu2.cica.es/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.1-6_amd64.deb

dpkg -i aircrack-ng_1.1-6_amd64.deb
```

Here is the help command

```
root@chillax:/usr/local/src# aircrack-ng --help

  Aircrack-ng 1.1 - (C) 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009 Thomas d'Otreppe   Original work: Christophe Devine   http://www.aircrack-ng.org

  usage: aircrack-ng [options] <.cap / .ivs file(s)>

  Common options:

      -a <amode> : force attack mode (1/WEP, 2/WPA-PSK)
      -e <essid> : target selection: network identifier
      -b <bssid> : target selection: access point's MAC
      -p <nbcpu> : # of CPU to use  (default: all CPUs)
      -q         : enable quiet mode (no status output)
      -C <macs>  : merge the given APs to a virtual one
      -l <file>  : write key to file

  Static WEP cracking options:

      -c         : search alpha-numeric characters only
      -t         : search binary coded decimal chr only
      -h         : search the numeric key for Fritz!BOX
      -d <mask>  : use masking of the key (A1:XX:CF:YY)
      -m <maddr> : MAC address to filter usable packets
      -n <nbits> : WEP key length :  64/128/152/256/512
      -i <index> : WEP key index (1 to 4), default: any
      -f <fudge> : bruteforce fudge factor,  default: 2
      -k <korek> : disable one attack method  (1 to 17)
      -x or -x0  : disable bruteforce for last keybytes
      -x1        : last keybyte bruteforcing  (default)
      -x2        : enable last  2 keybytes bruteforcing
      -X         : disable  bruteforce   multithreading
      -y         : experimental  single bruteforce mode
      -K         : use only old KoreK attacks (pre-PTW)
      -s         : show the key in ASCII while cracking
      -M <num>   : specify maximum number of IVs to use
      -D         : WEP decloak, skips broken keystreams
      -P <num>   : PTW debug:  1: disable Klein, 2: PTW
      -1         : run only 1 try to crack key with PTW

  WEP and WPA-PSK cracking options:

      -w <words> : path to wordlist(s) filename(s)
      -r <DB>    : path to airolib-ng database
                   (Cannot be used with -w)

      --help     : Displays this usage screen
```

See here for more : http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=downloads