# Can't download anything from Software Center

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center, package-management

I'm new to Ubuntu

```
Not found
There isn’t a software package called “codeblocks” in your current software sources.

Not found
There isn’t a software package called “vlc” in your current software sources
```

In terminal

```
Package 'aircrack-ng' has no installation candidate
Package 'vlc' has no installation candidate
```

And I can't find any software in Synaptic either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`codeblocks` and `vlc` are in the Universe component (see the [Repositories/Ubuntu community documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) page). `aircrack-ng` is not provided in Ubuntu 12.04's official software sources (though it is provided in the official software sources for previous Ubuntu releases, and will be provided again in Ubuntu 12.10).

I recommend fixing whatever problem is preventing `codeblocks` and `vlc` from being installed, before deciding which of the available methods you wish to use to install `aircrack-ng` (since, depending on how you install that, the same problem might get in the way if not fixed).

So, to install `codeblocks` and `vlc`, first make sure this component is enabled by going to **Edit** > **Software Sources...** in the Software Center's top menu bar, and checking the box labeled **Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)** (in the Ubuntu Software tab) *if it isn't already checked*. Then click **Close**.

[image: Software Sources window]

That should fix the problem. *Unless it was already checked*. **In that case, or if you know that you're also unable to install packages from the Main component (which is virtually always enabled, and you can see if it is in the same way), try the fix proposed in [r000000000000t](https://askubuntu.com/users/84082/r000000000000t)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/177361/22949).**

Once this is fixed and you're able to install `codeblocks` and `vlc`, go ahead and install `aircrack-ng` using one of the methods detailed in the answers here:

- [Can't install aircrack-ng](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142007/cant-install-aircrack-ng)

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```