# Cannot install aircrack-ng

Tags: 12.04, hp-pavilion, aircrack-ng

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t install aircrack-ng](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142007/cant-install-aircrack-ng)

Today I tried to install aircrack-ng. I used the command `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng` and it didn't work.

Here's what it says:

```
root @ Matej-HP home/mighty2361 :/ # apt-get install Aircrack-ng
Reading package lists ... made
Building dependency tree
Reading data on the state of ... made
Aircrack-ng package is not available, but it refers to another package.
This usually means that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source.
However the following packages replace
   iw: iw i386

E: Package 'Aircrack-ng' has no installation candidate
```

^^I used google translate for that because it is too hard to translate for me. I'm really sorry for that.

I have a HP Pavilion g7 1303 and Ubuntu 12.04.1 x64.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aircrack-ng has been removed from ubuntu repo. To build it, you need to follow the guide here

securit.se/en/2012/03/kompilera-reaver-ubuntu-12-04/

And here is a short guide

Install requirement

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
```

Grab the source and start building

```
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.1
nano common.mak
```

Then find

```
CFLAGS          ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3
```

And remove -Werror like this

```
CFLAGS          ?= -g -W -Wall -O3
```

Then start the install process

```
make
sudo make install
```

Done. Now you're ready to use aircrack-ng

Comment: I can only use the aircrack-ng command when i do it this way. I cannot use airmon-ng, airodump-ng, aireplay-ng, etc...