# Aircrack-ng installation error

Tags: installation, aircrack-ng

I want to install `aircrack-ng` tool on my Ubuntu 12.04 but I found errors while installation
when I give command make I got this
"

```
nosha@nosha-Inspiron-N4050:~/aircrack-ng-1.1$ make
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nosha/aircrack-ng-1.1/src'
make -C osdep
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nosha/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
Building for Linux
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nosha/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
gcc -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -fPIC -I..    -c -o linux.o linux.c
linux.c: In function ‘is_ndiswrapper’:
linux.c:165:17: error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function ‘linux_set_rate’:
linux.c:334:22: error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function ‘linux_set_channel’:
linux.c:807:22: error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function ‘linux_set_freq’:
linux.c:896:22: error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function ‘set_monitor’:
linux.c:1022:22: error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function ‘do_linux_open’:
linux.c:1366:12: error: variable ‘unused_str’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c:1352:15: error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function ‘get_battery_state’:
linux.c:1982:35: error: variable ‘current’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nosha/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nosha/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
make[1]: *** [osd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nosha/aircrack-ng-1.1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing Aircrack-ng on Ubuntu 12.04
The recent ubuntu 12.04 cut out aircrack-ng from their repository. So here is an easy step by step guild to get it installed again

apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.1
gedit common.mak

Replace the line

CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3

to:

CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -O3

Then save it and close gedit

make
sudo make install

for more info go through [Can't install aircrack-ng](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142007/cant-install-aircrack-ng)