# Step by Step guide to install aircrack-ng suite on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, aircrack-ng

I tried soo many guides and soo many things i browsed like the whole world wide web and I could not install aircrack-ng suite.
Any help would be appreciated :)
Thank you all,
Best regards.

Comment: What steps have you taken to install it, errors encountered?

Comment: I understand that this tool can crack WiFi passwords, but it can also be used for pen testing your own network (says `hakermania`), so, this is a legitimate question. Downvoters... please!

Comment: Also, this guide had worked for me: http://www.riyazwalikar.com/2010/12/installing-aircrack-ng-on-ubuntu-1204.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what steps you have taken, but **aircrack-ng** is in the "universe" repositories.

All you need to do is open up a terminal, and type in the following:

`sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`

This will install the whole suite, including airmon, airodump, and aireplay.

Make sure that you have the *universe* repository enabled. To do that, search and open the "Software Sources" from the dash, and make sure that the *universe* repository is checked (the highlighted one below).

[image]

**If** all of this still does not work, follow the steps listed in this answer [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/142011/52726).

Comment: sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you take a look at Backtrack Linux. Its a distribution for penetration testing with all the tools ready to use. Saved me alot of time during a class last semester.