# Unable to install any package or software

Tags: dependencies, aircrack-ng

I am a new user on Ubuntu. Currently, i am running Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on my PC. Lately, I've been facing problem in installing any software or package using terminal. I've also tried the following codes to fix this but it failed...

```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get clean
```

So this is how it looks like....

```
sajal@sajal-945GCMX-S2:~$ sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aircrack-ng : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: wireless-tools but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: iw but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: wget but it is not going to be installed
 minitube : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libphonon4 (>= 4:4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-script (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: phonon but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: phonon-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed or
                     phonon-backend
            Depends: dbus-x11 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Please help me with this........

Comment: Do this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Did you do this - `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the universe repository enabled.

[image]
This answer has been discussed in detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294651/step-by-step-guide-to-install-aircrack-ng-suite-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts).