# In apt-get, is there an option to assert that a package is a certain version number?

Tags: apt, docker, bitcoin

I'm running a Ubuntu-based Docker image to run a Bitcoin network in regtest mode. The docker image is in [this github repo](https://github.com/coinfoundry/bitcoin-private-testnet). After adding the PPA for Bitcoin, it seems that 0.15 of bitcoind installs instead of the new 0.16.2. I want to find out the source of the problem, and was wondering if there is a way to halt installation if the version number of a package doesn't match what I specify, and spit out an error if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

When I had that issue, I set up a build recipe for aircrack-ng when it wasn't in repo for a time - https://askubuntu.com/a/142015/5768 .  Build recipes are beautiful things.  They're also massive rep generators for fast moving projects on launchpad, but it's not relevant any more since it's back in either universe or multiverse.